# Can I create 2 components which share a state?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

In my React app, I have a layout file, and I want to be able to pass 2 different components into it. One component is to be shown in Area 1, and another is to be shown in Area 2.  Both components need to share information with each other.

So, my layout is:

```
const SplitLayout = (Area1Content, Area2Content) => {

  return (
    <div className="area1">
      <Area1Content />
    </div>
    <div className="area2">
      <Area2Content />
    </div>
  );

}

export default SplitLayout;
```

In my App.js I have:

```
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={ROUTES.HOME} 
             render={(props) => 
                       <SplitLayout {...props} 
                                    Area1Content={HomeContent} 
                                    Area2Content={SidebarContent} />}/>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);

export default App;
```

This works fine; I can put `HomeContent` and `SidebarContent` into a file and export both of them, and they are shown correctly.

However, I want to be able to pass information from one to the other, so, for instance, `SidebarContent` has a list of names; when I click on a name in the list, I want that person's details to be shown in `HomeContent` (so in the `HomeContent` component I can have a state variable called `currentPerson`, and when a name is clicked in `SidebarContent`, the value of `currentPerson` should be changed).

Is there a way to achieve this?

I have several pages with similar layouts, so what I'm hoping is that I can have, eg, a `HomeComponent.js` file which has `HomeContent` and `SidebarContent`, and then another component called, say, `SecondComponent.js` which has `SecondContent` and `SecondSidebar`, so I can just add a new Route to App, something like:

```
<Route exact path={ROUTES.SECOND} 
                 render={(props) => 
                           <SplitLayout {...props} 
                                        Area1Content={SecondContent} 
                                        Area2Content={SecondSidebar} />}/>
```

so it will render the same layout but with different components.  I know I could lift the state up to the top level, but there could potentially be several different component pairs, each needing to pass info, and I think it would get messy to manage all of them at the App level.  Is there a better way?

EDIT: I think what I want to do is something like this:

In `App.js` my route would be something like:

```
<Route exact path={ROUTES.HOME} 
       render={(props) => 
               <SplitLayout {...props} 
                            PageContent={WrapperComponent} />}/>
```

Then in the `SplitLayout` file I'd have something like:

```
const SplitLayout = (WrapperComponent) => {

  return (
    <div className="area1">
      <WrapperComponent.Area1Content/>
    </div>
    <div className="area2">
      <WrapperComponent.Area2Content/>
    </div>
  );

}
```

And `WrapperComponent` would be something like:

```
const WrapperComponent = () => {

  const [myStateVariable, setMyState] = useState("xyz")

  const Area1Content = () => {
    return (<div>{myStateVariable}</div>);
  }

  const Area2Content = () => {
    return (<div onClick={setMyState("abc")}>Something else</div>);
  }

}

export default WrapperComponent;
```

Is there a way to do something like that?

Answer (score 3):

You can put the shared state in the parent component, and pass it down as props.

Comment: This. Also she can use redux so she doesn't need to write all the states in the parent.

Comment: Yes or use the Context API if you don't want a separate library

Comment: So put the state in App.js?  I'm trying to avoid that as it would get quite cluttered.  I guess what I want is to have a sort of wrapper component for HomeContent and SidebarContent, so I can tell App.js to use WrapperComponent, and then WrapperComponent manages the state and exports HomeContent and SidebarContent.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I'll look into redux as well.  Context API could work too, although again I'm worried it would get cluttered - I'll look into it some more though.